# Change font size of summary in Preference

Tags: android, preferenceactivity, text-size

Does anybody know how to change the font size of both title and summary?

If I define my own style and set

```
<item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
```

Both the title and summary are set to this size. I want to make the summary 24sp, but I can't seem to find a way.

Comment: so many time and no answer. Have somebody solved this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try define a different style in the styles.xml and set the first with the textSize 30sp and the second with 24sp

```
<style name="title">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>

<style name="summary">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

and set the style using the lines where you want to use.

```
style="@style/title"
```

or

```
style="@style/summary"
```

I hope this helps.